# i am trying to fetch the id of the image to display it in full view

Tags: java, android, gridview

Below is the class where i am not able to get the resource of the image id. I am trying to fetch all the data from the web service. Here i have posted all the classes from where the images are fetched.I have all the images showing it in the gridView. I am not facing problem in that, however when I click on the image of the gridview it shows me the just the xml file which I have called. I guess I am doing wrong somewhere calling the id here in the FullImageAcitivity file.

DefaultGridView.java

```
 public class DefaultGridView  extends Activity {


//int position;

public void onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onBackPressed();
finish();

}

GridView gridView;
Context context=this;
DisplayImageOptions options;
protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.latestphotos);

        gridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
        .cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();


        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);



        public ImageAdapter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(DefaultGridView.this));
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Global.getPhotos_list().size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View v = view;
            ImageView picture;
            TextView name;


            if(v == null) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other, viewGroup, false);
                v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
                v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
            }

            picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
            name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

            Item item = (Item)items.get(i);
            picture.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
            name.setText(item.name);
            Log.d("position", position+"");

            imageLoader.displayImage(Constant.img_URL+Global.getPhotos_list().get(position).get("photo_name"), picture , options,null,context);
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long a) {




                      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                      i.putExtra("idkey", position); // pass the id
                      startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            return v;



        }
    }
}
```

FullImageActivity.java

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {



Button download, setas;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);




    setas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setas);




    download = (Button)findViewById(R.id.download);



 // get intent data
    final Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id




    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("idkey",-1); //get id
    imageView.setImageResource(id);

    setas.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
             = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.id.full_image_view);
            } catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater;

List<Item> items;
public ImageAdapter(Context context,List<Item> items) {
 inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 this.items = items;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return items.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return items.get(i).drawable;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    ImageView picture;
    TextView name;

    if(v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other, viewGroup, false);
        v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
    }

    picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
    name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

    Item item = (Item)items.get(i);
    picture.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
    name.setText(item.name);

    return v;
}

}
```

Items.java

```
public class Item {
String name;
int drawable;
 public int getDrawable() {
  return drawable;
}
public void setDrawable(int drawable) {
this.drawable = drawable;
}
public Item(String name, int id)
{
this.name= name;
this.drawable = id;
}
public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

Comment: why is that you have ImageAdapter twice? one as a inner class the other in separate .java file?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. download the sample and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gridView item click

```
Item item =(Item) items.get(position);
int  id = item.getDrawable(); 
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this, FullImageActivity.class);
i.putExtra("idkey", id); // pass the id
startActivity(i);
```

Then in FullImageActivity

```
int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("idkey"); //get id
imageview.setImageResource(id); // set the drawable to imageview
```

You can move the below to onCreate of DefaultFridView

```
  gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long a) {
                Item item =(Item) items.get(position);
                int  id = item.getDrawable(); 
                Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this, FullImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("idkey", id); // pass the id
                startActivity(i);

                }
            });
```

Also you need to have the List in DefaultGridView

```
 List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Then

```
items.add(new Item("One", R.drawable.abstact_one));
items.add(new Item("Two",  R.drawable.abstract_three));
items.add(new Item("Three", R.drawable.image_two));
items.add(new Item("Four", R.drawable.image_four));
items.add(new Item("Five", R.drawable.image_five));
items.add(new Item("Six",  R.drawable.image_nine));
items.add(new Item("Seven", R.drawable.image_ten));
```

Then

```
 gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(),items);
```

Also i don't understand having the ImageAdapter as separate and as a inner class. WHy do you need both

Comment: We havent used static array adapter here.. so we are not using Items to call the same in DefaultGridView.java, when we pasted your code in it, it shows the error in items. the first line.

Comment: but you have the adapter class twice. also what is the error.

Comment: the error is because you need to have the list in your defaultgridview but you do not have one andi don't see where you populate your items in image adapter

Comment: Its because our entire data is coming from webservice.the images which are in the gridView are not static..!!

Comment: then show me the code where you populate the items. coz you are using the same in imageadapter and why is that you have adapter twice. deos not make sense

Comment: As you told me, it is useless to use two image adapter, i have fixed that, and its working fine now, however i am facing new problem here, i am getting resource id of the particular image when i click, but my  logcat shows the error of "resource not found", however the images are there on the webserver thats  the reason we are able to c the same in gridview.

Comment: @DeepRathod if the resource is not found ie its not available it give you resource not found exception. You are actually getting the index of list item clikc ie position. position gives you the index of list item. cache the images and display it in full image activity later. or pass the url of the image and then download it again full image activity and display it in imageview. the smaple here is awesome http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. try it

Comment: gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> viewGroup, View v,
                      int position, long a) {
   
                 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                 i.putExtra("idkey", position); // pass the id
                 startActivity(i);
              }
          });
          return v; }

Comment: @DeepRathod i wil reply once i get back home. now going out. any way youcan either post the code here or if you need help beyound stackoverflow you can zip the code i will check and reply back

Answer (score 0):

Try this example my be it is usefull

[Grieview Display Full Image](http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-gridview-with-full-image.html)